# asp.net Javascript window.location Url.Action not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I try to get a JavaScript working within ASP.NET
My JavaScript:

```
 function reportOrder(sender, args) {
    alert("Message");

    window.location.href = @Url.Action("StartReport", "PrintOut", New With {.Area = "Printing", Key .ReportName = "Test",
                                                    Key .typeOfReport = TypeOfPrintingIS.Order,
                                                    Key .CompanyId = DirectCast(ViewData("CompanyId"), Guid),
                                                    Key .ExchangePrintData = CType(locOrderReport, ExchangeData.IExchangePrintData)});

}
```

First of all, the function works, when I disable the window.location, the alert is raised! So, the Problem has to be within the @UrlAction(

And also, the Area is working, because, when I use a similar Html.RenderAction function with an other directive to another function, it works fine.

The function within the Controller:

```
 <HttpPost>
    Function StartReport(ReportName As String, typeOfReport As TypeOfPrintingIS, CompanyId As Guid, ExchangePrintData As Code.ExchangeData.IExchangePrintData) As ActionResult
        Dim model As New HTML5ViewerModel()
        model.ViewerOptions.UseUIMiniStyle = True
        locReportHelper.CompanyId = CompanyId
        locReportHelper.ReportName = ReportName
        locReportHelper.TypeOfReport = typeOfReport
        locReportHelper.ExchangePrintData = ExchangePrintData
        model.ReportName = locReportHelper.CreateReportId

        Return View("Html5Viewer", model)
    End Function
```

And the "IExchangePrintData" Interface is an empty Interface to verify the correct class.

Does anyone of you got an idea?
THX a lot - Have a nice weekend

Comment: Any errors in browser console while using `@Url.Action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your razor directive with single quotation marks. It looks like this one:  `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SomeActionName", "SomeControllerName", etc...)';`
Guess this should work, cause of you mentioned `@Html.RenderAction` worked fine.

Comment: THX a lot! - This was the Magic key!